# Ajax multiple echos from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Say, I have a php file like this:

```
<?php 
echo 1;
//some functions
echo 2;
//more code to execute
echo 3;
?>
```

And I have an html form. So what I want in this form is to print echos in some textfield while PHP script is being executed, is it possible with AJAX and JQuery?

What I want is that user enters HTML page, presses some button, this button runs PHP script and every time script reaches echo he can see this echo in textfield. Once script is over - I want to do some JQuery action, like hide button, for example. Is it possible? What would an overview algorithm be? Thanks!

**UPDATE**:
I need to run this script ONCE when user presses button, but update textfield every time script reaches next echo, so that user presses button once, than he will see "1" in textfield, in a second he will see "2", in few more seconds - "3".

Comment: to run php script every time click on button you need to make ajax call

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, since the `success` handler of `.ajax()` will only be called once the request has **finished**, you **can't** do a "live update".. :(

All you can really do is save your current state in a session, end your script at each echo and re-request the page to continue.

Answer (score 3):

You can use two ways either return the response as `json`

```
$values = array();
$values['first'] => 1;
$values['second'] => 2;
$values['third'] => 3;
print json_encode($values);
```

and in the client side jquery `success` handler

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yoururl',
    type:'POST',
    data :'{ if any }'
    dataType:'json', /*most important**/ 
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data.first); //first value..etc
    }
    });
```

second method

Append the return data on the server side

```
$return= '';
$return.=1."||";
$return.=2."||";
$return.=3;
echo $return;exit;
```

and in the ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yoururl',
    type:'POST',
    data :'{ if any }'
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data.split("||")[0]); //first value..etc
    }
    });
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You could return a JSON-string that PHP creates for your:

```
$values = array();
$values['first'] => 1;
$values['second'] => 2;
$values['third'] => 3;
print json_encode( values );
```

Than store this response in a JavaScript variable and use the values of it to update at the specific time:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
// as an example - to see where this goes
setTimeout(function() { $('#example').html(obj.first); }, 1000);
```

More information:

- [PHP json_encode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php)
- [jQuery jQuery.parseJSON((](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution by using two `php` scripts:

- first is your actual one, which will store out data in session instead of echoing them
- second script will just echo data stored in the session

Your client in `javascript`, will call the first script to launch the main job. Then call the second script to check and show advancement.

The second script which checks the session can be written in two ways:

- only check and directly return, with or without new data (you call it every second by example)
- return directly if there is data, else just wait for data (or a timeout), and when the script returns you just recall him

The second solution is closer to "realtime" and will do much fewer `ajax` calls.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), it will allow "real time" communication between your PHP and Javascript.

Native WebSockets are only supported by newer versions of modern browsers, but there is some method for old browsher to emulate this, using ajax/iframe/flash

by exemple, the [socket.io](http://socket.io/) client can work with internet explorer 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

I had one such requirement. I noticed that though jquery's ajax ie. using $.ajax does not allow it. But using ajax without jquery does accept multiple echoes from php.

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
              
            ajax.open("POST", url, true);
          
            ajax.send();

                ajax.onreadystatechange = function ( ) 
            {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
                {
                     console.log(this.responseText)
                }
            };
```